# How to save pdf generated by webform2pdf on server with every webform submission in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

`How to save PDFs generated by webform2pdf on server with every web form

submission in drupal 7`

Answer (score 0):

PDF file is rendered on client machine when you request to download PDF so saving it on server is not possible as per a previous discussion https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29096/save-pdf-file-using-webform2pdf

It however is possible when using "Printer, email and PDF " module by hacking the module like described here https://www.drupal.org/node/801680

Comment: As mentioned in the above link i tried saving the file using curl by grabing the path of pdf generated but the file saved on the server is not getting opened.